# changing values inside array swift at an index

Tags: swift

I am a high school student new to swift and I can't seem to be able to change a boolean value at in index, this is my variable

```
var value = [[String:Bool]]()
value.append(["Club 1" : true])
```

I want to be able to change the value to `false` no matter how many values that I append.

I found out that you can reference them like

```
value[0].values.first!
```

but I want to be able to change it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
value[ 0 ][ "Club 1" ] = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following function.

```
func findIndexOfDictionary(inArray array: [[String: Bool]], #withKey: String) -> Int? {
    for index in 0..<array.count {
        if array[index][withKey] != nil {
            return index
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

If there are no duplicate keys in any of your dictionaries, this function will return the index to the dictionary containing the key or nil if it doesn't exist.

In the Playground screen capture you can see the return value for an existing key 'Spades 2', changing the value of 'Club 1', and not finding a key 'Heart 1'.

[image]

Here is a more terse version of the same function using the higher order, `filter` function.

```
func findIndexOfDictionary(inArray array: [[String: Bool]], withKey key: String) -> Int? {
    return (filter(0..<array.count){array[$0][key] != nil}).first
}
```